# Why $u_n \rightarrow 0$ in $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

**Definition 1.1.1 ( $\mathcal{G}$-weak convergence)**. Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a set of homeomorphisms $E \rightarrow E$. One says that a sequence $\left(u_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $E$ is $\mathcal{G}$-weakly convergent to a point $u \in E$ relative to the set $\mathcal{G}$, if for any sequence $\left(g_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathcal{G}, g_n\left(u_n-u\right)$ is weakly convergent to zero in $E$. In this case, we use the notation $u_n \stackrel{\mathcal{G}}{-} u$.

**Definition 1.1.4 (Cocompact embedding)**. One says that a continuous embedding $E \hookrightarrow F$ of two Banach spaces is cocompact relative to a set $\mathcal{G}$ of homeomorphisms $E \rightarrow E$ if for any sequence $\left(u_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $E$,
$$
u_n \stackrel{\mathcal{G}}{\rightarrow} 0 \text { in } E \Longrightarrow\left\|u_n\right\|_F \rightarrow 0
$$

Remark 1.1.5. Obviously, if $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{G}^{\prime}$, then a $\mathcal{G}$-cocompact embedding is also $\mathcal{G}^{\prime}$ cocompact.

**Example 1.1.6 (Stephane Jaffard, [68])**. The embedding $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z}) \hookrightarrow \ell^r(\mathbb{Z}), 1 \leq p<r \leq$ $\infty$, is not compact, since any sequence of the form $u_n=u(\cdot+n), n \in \mathbb{N}, u \in \ell^p$, converges to zero weakly in $\ell^p$, while the $\ell^p$-norm on the sequence is constant.

On the other hand, this embedding is cocompact relative to the group $\mathcal{G}_{\mathbb{Z}}=\{u \mapsto u(\cdot-j)\}_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$.
$$ \ell^p(\mathbb{Z}) :=\{u \
| \ \left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|u(n)|^p\right)^{1 / p}<\infty \}
$$
Indeed, consider a sequence $\left(u_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\ell^p$ that converges to zero $\mathcal{G}_{\mathbb{Z}}$-weakly, that is, such that $u_n\left(\cdot+j_n\right) \rightarrow 0$ in $\ell^p$ for any sequence $j_n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $u_n\left(j_n\right) \rightarrow 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for any sequence $\left(j_n\right)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, which implies

***(why?)***$ u_n \rightarrow 0$ in $\ell^{\infty}$.***(why?)***

Since $\|u\|_r^r \leq\|u\|_{\infty}^{r-p}\|u\|_p^p$, one has $u_n \rightarrow 0$ in $\ell^r$ for all $r>p$. We conclude that the embedding $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z}) \hookrightarrow \ell^r(\mathbb{Z}), 1 \leq p<r \leq \infty$, is $\mathcal{G}_{\mathbb{Z}}$-cocompact. Furthermore, the same argument shows that $\ell^{\infty}$ is $\mathcal{G}_{\mathbb{Z}}$-cocompactly embedded into itself.

Comment: Proof by contradiction works.